# Fixing the size of ingredient in the tables' cells

Tags: tables

I have created a table as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\kern\tabcolsep}l<{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Indicators for sustainable transportation \citep{r2}}
    \label{tab: ind}
            \centering
                \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l L L L @{} >{\kern\tabcolsep}l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{Objective} & \emph{Indicator} & \emph{Direction} &&&  \\\midrule

\emph{Economic}    &    &    &    &    \\ 
\rowcolor{black!3}[0pt][0pt] Transport diversity & Mode split: portion of travel made by walking, cycling, rideshare, public transit and telework & More is better \\

\emph{Social}    &    &    &    &    \\ 
\rowcolor{black!6}[0pt][0pt] Health and fitness & Percentage of population that regularly walks and cycles & More is better \\
\rowcolor{black!8}[0pt][0pt] Non-motorized transport planning & Degree to which impacts on non-motorized transport are considered in transportation modeling and planning & More is better \\

\emph{Environmental}    &    &    &    &    \\ 
\rowcolor{black!10}[0pt][0pt] Resource efficiency & Non-renewable resource consumption in the production and use of vehicles and transport facilities & Less is better \\
\rowcolor{black!12}[0pt][0pt] Climate change emissions & Per capita fossil fuel consumption, and emissions of CO2 and other climate change emissions & Less is better \\
\rowcolor{black!14}[0pt][0pt] Noise pollution & Portion of population exposed to high levels of traffic noise & Less is better \\

 \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the output is presented as:

[image]

As you can see part of the table in out of the border. The problem is caused because the cell's texts are long.

How can I fix it, automatically?

Comment: `l`-, `r`- and `c`-columns do not break their contents. Consider using `p`-columns, or perhaps `X`-columns from [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

Comment: @Werner Would you please be more specific?

Comment: Your second column (the one that is overrunning the page boundary) uses an `L`-type, which is defined to be based on an `l`-type (using `\newcolumntype{L}`). These types of columns (`l`, `r` and `c`) *do not* wrap its contents. Instead all the text will always be put on a single line. A `p{<len>}`-column (where you specify a `<len>` verbatim) *will* wrap the text though. [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) provides an `X`-column that measure the width automatically, and can be used to spread out columns evenly. You have to specify the width of the `tabularx` though.

Comment: @Werner, Unfortunately, the problem still exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating on Werner's comments.  You can use column type `p` to specify specific widths for columns.  In your example with the backgrounds it seems easiest to me to specify blank columns to hold the coloured inter-column space:

[image: First sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{Indicators for sustainable transportation}
  \label{tab: ind}
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{10pt} p{5cm} p{10pt} l}    \toprule
    \emph{Objective} && \emph{Indicator} && \emph{Direction}  \\\midrule
    \emph{Economic}     &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!3}[0pt][0pt] Transport diversity && Mode split: portion of travel made by walking, cycling, rideshare, public transit and telework && More is better \\
    \emph{Social}       &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!6}[0pt][0pt] Health and fitness && Percentage of population that regularly walks and cycles && More is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!8}[0pt][0pt] Non-motorized transport planning && Degree to which impacts on non-motorized transport are considered in transportation modeling and planning && More is better \\
    \emph{Environmental}       &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!10}[0pt][0pt] Resource efficiency && Non-renewable resource consumption in the production and use of vehicles and transport facilities && Less is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!12}[0pt][0pt] Climate change emissions && Per capita fossil fuel consumption, and emissions of CO2 and other climate change emissions && Less is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!14}[0pt][0pt] Noise pollution && Portion of population exposed to high levels of traffic noise && Less is better \\
    \bottomrule
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use `tabularx` to get variable width columns with an `X` specification.  You now have to specify a total width for the table:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl,tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{Indicators for sustainable transportation}
  \label{tab: ind}
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X p{10pt} >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}X p{10pt} l}    \toprule
    \emph{Objective} && \emph{Indicator} && \emph{Direction}  \\\midrule
    \emph{Economic}     &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!3}[0pt][0pt] Transport diversity && Mode split: portion of travel made by walking, cycling, rideshare, public transit and telework && More is better \\
    \emph{Social}       &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!6}[0pt][0pt] Health and fitness && Percentage of population that regularly walks and cycles && More is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!8}[0pt][0pt] Non-motorized transport planning && Degree to which impacts on non-motorized transport are considered in transportation modeling and planning && More is better \\
    \emph{Environmental}       &&    &&    \\ 
    \rowcolor{black!10}[0pt][0pt] Resource efficiency && Non-renewable resource consumption in the production and use of vehicles and transport facilities && Less is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!12}[0pt][0pt] Climate change emissions && Per capita fossil fuel consumption, and emissions of CO2 and other climate change emissions && Less is better \\
    \rowcolor{black!14}[0pt][0pt] Noise pollution && Portion of population exposed to high levels of traffic noise && Less is better \\
    \bottomrule
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here I used two `X` columns, each with a specification `>{\hsize=x\hsize}`.  It is important that the sum of the `x`s is the number of `X` columns.  The ratios between the `x`s gives the ratio of the widths of the corresponding `X` columns.